# Symfony2: How to test Configuration nodes values and index

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony-2.1

In Symfony2, using this class setup, how can I test that each nodes is defined in the `Configuration` class, and that their values are correctly configured.

**The class to test**

```
# My\Bundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration.php

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $treeBuilder->root('my_bundle')
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode("scalar")->defaultValue("defaultValue")->end()
                ->arrayNode("arrayNode")
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode("val1")->defaultValue("defaultValue1")->end()
                        ->scalarNode("val2")->defaultValue("defaultValue2")->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

Here are the assertions I would like to do, in my unit test:

I tried to access the nodes as an array, but it do not seems to work. Also the `TreeBuilder` do not seems to give us the possibility of getting the configurations as a array, unless they are loaded by the bundle extension.

**Tests**

```
# My\Bundle\Tests\DependencyInjection\ConfigurationTest.php

$configuration = $this->getConfiguration();
$treeBuilder   = $configuration->getConfigTreeBuilder();

$this->assertInstanceOf("Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder", $treeBuilder);

// How to access the treebuilder's nodes ?
$rootNode   = $treeBuilder["my_bundle"];
$scalarNode = $treeBuilder["scalar"];
$arrayNode  = $treeBuilder["arrayNode"];
$val1Node   = $arrayNode["val1"];
$val2Node   = $arrayNode["val2"];

$this->assertInstanceOf("Symfony\...\ArrayNodeDefinition", $rootNode);
$this->assertEquals("defaultValue", $scalarNode, "Test the default value of the node");
$this->assertEquals("defaultValue", $val1Node, "Test the default value of the node");
$this->assertEquals("defaultValue", $val2Node, "Test the default value of the node");
```

Comment: I don't think it is actualy good idea to test configuration and also test it that way.

Comment: @Ziumin, What method would you suggest to ensure that a value has a default value set, or the a default service id should be confirgured...

Comment: I suggest preparing a test set of congigurations and checking if they are processed correctly with your Configuration class

Comment: @Ziumin, Would my answer be the right way too. Because, the only problem I see with it, is that The test is dedendant on another component instead of only testing the `Configuration` class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found out a solution that could work based on [JMSSecurityBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/blob/master/Tests/DependencyInjection/JMSSecurityExtraExtensionTest.php).

Instead of testing the configuration, I test the extension which will add coverage for the configuration by the way. That way, I can assert that a default configuration was set.

For instance, this `Extension`.

```
#My\Bundle\DependencyInjection\MyBundleExtension
class MyBundleExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config        = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $container->setParameter("crak_landing_frontend.scalar", $config["scalar"]);
        $container->setParameter("crak_landing_frontend.array_node", $config["array_node"]);

        $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.xml');
    }
}
```

Could be tests like:

```
#My\Bundle\Tests\DependencyInjection\MyBundleExtensionTest
class MyBundleExtensionTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var MyBundleExtension
     */
    private $extension;

    /**
     * Root name of the configuration
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $root;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->extension = $this->getExtension();
        $this->root      = "my_bundle";
    }

    public function testGetConfigWithDefaultValues()
    {
        $this->extension->load(array(), $container = $this->getContainer());

        $this->assertTrue($container->hasParameter($this->root . ".scalar"));
        $this->assertEquals("defaultValue", $container->getParameter($this->root . ".scalar"));

        $expected = array(
            "val1" => "defaultValue1",
            "val2" => "defaultValue2",
        );
        $this->assertTrue($container->hasParameter($this->root . ".array_node"));
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $container->getParameter($this->root . ".array_node"));
    }

    public function testGetConfigWithOverrideValues()
    {
        $configs = array(
            "scalar"     => "scalarValue",
            "array_node" => array(
                "val1" => "array_value_1",
                "val2" => "array_value_2",
            ),
        );

        $this->extension->load(array($configs), $container = $this->getContainer());

        $this->assertTrue($container->hasParameter($this->root . ".scalar"));
        $this->assertEquals("scalarValue", $container->getParameter($this->root . ".scalar"));

        $expected = array(
            "val1" => "array_value_1",
            "val2" => "array_value_2",
        );
        $this->assertTrue($container->hasParameter($this->root . ".array_node"));
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $container->getParameter($this->root . ".array_node"));
    }

    /**
     * @return MyBundleExtension
     */
    protected function getExtension()
    {
        return new MyBundleExtension();
    }

    /**
     * @return ContainerBuilder
     */
    private function getContainer()
    {
        $container = new ContainerBuilder();

        return $container;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To test your configuration **in isolation**, you can do this :

```
use Foo\YourBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ConfigurationTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider dataTestConfiguration
     *
     * @param mixed $inputConfig
     * @param mixed $expectedConfig
     */
    public function testConfiguration($inputConfig, $expectedConfig)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();

        $node = $configuration->getConfigTreeBuilder()
            ->buildTree();
        $normalizedConfig = $node->normalize($inputConfig);
        $finalizedConfig = $node->finalize($normalizedConfig);

        $this->assertEquals($expectedConfig, $finalizedConfig);
    }

    public function dataTestConfiguration()
    {
        return [
            'test configuration'   => [
                ['input'],
                ['expected_config']
            ],
            // ...
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this great example 